# symfony inserting data using doctrine and retrieving it using php

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm working on a symfony2 project. when i insert data with french accents like (é), it is inserted as shown in this image:
[image]

when i try to retrieve this data using a php file to use it in android app, i use this code:

```
<?php
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASS','');
    define('DB','adproject');
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect to db');
$sql = "select * from actualite";

$result = array();

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    array_push($result,
    array('id'=>$row[0],
    'login'=>$row[1],
    'password'=>$row[2]
    ));

    }
echo json_encode($result); 


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I get nothing because of the accents in the database. Any suggestion?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the old deprecated `mysqli_` function calls! Just to let you know, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you'll need to go through this Configuring the Database section and setting up for UTF8:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database

Let us know if you've already done that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can i find the my.cnf file?

Comment: It might not be called `my.cnf` file. I'm using CentOS, and the file to change is `server.cnf` located in the path `/etc/my.cnf.d`. Which Linux distro are you using, or are you on Windows?

Comment: I made the configuration , now the (é) is saved in database as Â© and retrieved as "\u00a9", how can i show it again as (é)?

Comment: You might have to clean out your database. Try deleting those rows manually. It might be a good idea to delete the database and run `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`, and then retry your code.

Comment: I think this is how json_encode is supposed to show the data, so my probleme is solved ;)